# Google Apps scripts called from Google sites now (suddenly) returning 404 error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, http-status-code-404, google-sites, multiple-accounts

I have a Google site (https://sites.google.com/site/kitchenergaffers/) which has many pages where scripts are launched. This morning (18 August 2020 EDT) I see that none of the script pages are working and the script seems to be reporting a 404 error of some sort.

The scripts interact with a series of Google sheets

Here is an example of one such page
https://sites.google.com/site/kitchenergaffers/home/general-gaffers-information/publish/directory-of-results?display=directory

=============
404. That's an error.

## The requested URL /accounts was not found on this server. That's all we know.

There are many pages that run the same script, and some pages that have different scripts.
All scripts are set to run Anonymously, anyone can execute

Nothing on the site or within the scripts code or Sheets has changed to create this issue.

UPDATE: Although the error comes up using Chrome browser when logged into the creator account, or my personal account if I open an incognito window they run correctly!

UPDATE2: My PC suffered a Windows update yesterday that may be related however, my Chromebook shows the same problem. This problem does not happen if I use Edge browser.

UPDATE3: If I log out of all my accounts, and only sign in to one of them, the problem does not happen. Once I log into an additional account, the problem recurs. Signing out of all, then back into one only is then necessary.

Comment: Try logging into additional accounts with a different browser

Comment: Hi there @RickLugg! I don't understand your issue, could you please clarify it to me? I checked the example page and it shows data just fine; I don't see any 404 error, what is wrong there? To prevent any trigger issue, please confirm if you are using them at all. Also, could you please share the script that fires the error so we all can take a look?

Comment: I appreciate the comments and suggestions. As of mid-day 19th August EDT the problem seemed to have gone away. I can only guess that it is something to do with being logged into the "owner" account of the scripts but it is not consistent. If I logged out of that account and back in again, the pages worked OK once or twice and then went back to giving the issue.
 
I had marked is as "Answered" but it clearly is not yet solved

Comment: Basically the problem seems to be limited to me (or one of my accounts). I am currently speculating it is related to being signed into the account that "owns" the script that runs on the page, but I am not really sure at all.

Comment: It is not getting into starting the script. The error comes up right at the beginning. Currently (17:30 EDT) I have opened it in one tab and it is OK and in another tab it shows "Google Drive - Unable to Open the File at this time. Please check the address and try again" Yesterday was an even less helpful message "Something has gone wrong!"

Comment: .. and to be clear. It is not only one script that is being used. I have other pages with other scripts that have an identical problem, but only seems to be affecting my account as I have had no complaints from other users of the site - wierd

Comment: I still have no explanation for the problem, but have narrowed it down. On my PC if I sign out of my main gmail account all works well on my PC - this presumably is why none of the users see a problem. On my phone (Android) and Chromebook, the same error shows up unless I use "incognito" mode of Chrome on those devices.

That main account is an "editor" for the website, and the scripts, but not the owner

Answer (score 1):

as of 15:00EDT  20 August the issue seems to be resolved. I am not sure if it was something I did experimentally or what, but it has gone.

As it seemed to be related to my account and using Chrome I turned off sync, cleared cookies (also disabling Chrome extensions and bookmarks it seems) then "repaired" or reenabled extensions, resync'd to get the bookmarks from the Chromebook or phone and tried again.

The issue seems to have been resolved - maybe by these actions :)